# Is there any way to encrypt SQLite Database on External SD-Card?

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-sqlite, android-file

I'm creating an app which has its predefined SQLite database on external SD-Card with some videos | images & PDFs in SD-Card folder. 
I have heard of encrypting database using "PRAGMA". But I think this isn't safe. 
Can I encrypt the file and database using a key and reuse this SD-Card in another phone having my App installed?
Is there any other alternative solution available for reference?

Encrypting Database :

```
class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
      db.execSQL("PRAGMA key = 'secretkey'");
    }
}
```

Encryption Helper Functions :

```
public static byte[] generateKey(String password) throws Exception
{
    byte[] keyStart = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
    sr.setSeed(keyStart);
    kgen.init(128, sr);
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    return skey.getEncoded();
}

public static byte[] encodeFile(byte[] key, byte[] fileData) throws Exception
{

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return encrypted;
}

public static byte[] decodeFile(byte[] key, byte[] fileData) throws Exception
    {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        return decrypted;
    }
```

To save encrypted file to SD-Card :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "your_folder_on_sd", "file_name");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
byte[] yourKey = generateKey("password");
byte[] filesBytes = encodeFile(yourKey, yourByteArrayContainigDataToEncrypt);
bos.write(fileBytes);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

To Decode file :

```
byte[] yourKey = generateKey("password");
byte[] decodedData = decodeFile(yourKey, bytesOfYourFile);
```

Comment: "I have heard of encrypting database using "PRAGMA". But I think this isn't safe" -- SQLite does not offer this. SQLCipher does, and it is as safe or safer than what you propose. "Can I encrypt the file and database using a key and reuse this SD-Card in another phone having my App installed?" -- yes, but... what are you defending against? You have to decrypt the database to a plain SQLite file to use it with SQLite. So, if you are defending against the SD card being lost, your encryption is fine. But your approach still leaves the database unencrypted on the device.

Comment: Also note that your encryption code is out of date, as `SHA1PRNG` [was deprecated three years ago](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html).

Comment: If the SD Card gets stolen, can any one get the SQLite Database contents or preview the files(images, videos or pdfs) ? Basic need is to view the database or files only from my app

Comment: Which is the best encryption technique that suite the situation ?

Comment: If you do not mind having the database be decrypted on the device, and you only need it encrypted on the removable media, then your file encryption approach is fine (though, please use up-to-date code). If you do not want the database to be saved as a plain SQLite database on the device, then you need to use SQLCipher for Android or something else that decrypts the data on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, SQLCipher is what I need !!

Comment: I have one more query!! Its about encrypting the files! Which encryption mechanism is Prefered ?